# Error Exporting Access Table to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2013

I am using the below lines of code to export an access table that holds roughly 7,000 lines to Excel 2013, but I keep getting an error.  What do I need to do in order to resolve this error so I can export my table to Excel?

```
outputFileName = "C:\Users\user123\Documents\Database_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ALL_Table", outputFileName, True
```

And this is the error that is thrown

> because the file format or file extensions is not valid.  Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of this file.

Comment: have you tried debugging your code? What is the value of "outputfilename" after the first line is executed? Why do you use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` instead of `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász - yes I have stepped through my code line by line.  I have tried to change the format to acSpreadSheetTypeExcel12, as well as the value in my post.  the value of outputfilename is the filepath and filename that it shoudl be saved as.  If I change .xlsx to .xls it will save but give a warning about file type etc.  so I know the syntax is okay.